# Data Directory PostgreSQL 9.1 to Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

"My predecessor" has installed PostgreSQL 9.1, now I would like to know what is the "Data Directory" installation.

Now I am using this interface:

[image]

Can I know using this interface the Data Directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start PGAdmin3 , connect server , select Tools -> Server Configuration -> postgresql.conf, and look for data_directory variable

Answer (score 1):

As a superuser you could run the query

```
SHOW data_directory;
```

From https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/how-do-i-find-postgresqls-data-directory

Comment: Thanks hmallet also your solution is correct, but now I am still a beginner GUI  PGAdmin3 helps me a lot. Thanks.